# how to resolve sorting error of mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am getting this error while sorting through mongoose :
TypeError: Invalid sort value: {field: submittedDate }
My Code part is:

```
var image = mongoose.model('Image');
var allImages =  image.find({reviewed:true },null,{sort:{"submittedDate":-1}}, function (err, images)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            logger.info("Error occured");
            throw err;
        }
        else
        {
            logger.info("images sorted are:",images);
            cb(images);
        }

    });
```

any help will be appriciated.

Comment: It would help if you posted the code that's hitting this error.

Comment: var allImages =  image.find({reviewed:true },null,{sort:{"submittedDate":-1}}, function (err, images)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            logger.info("Error occured");
            throw err;
        }
        else
        {
            logger.info("images sorted are:",images);
            cb(images);
        }

    });

Comment: Edit your question to include the code instead of putting that in a comment, and also include an example document from the `image` collection.

Comment: editted my question kindly help now.

Comment: Your `model` call needs to include a second parameter that defines the schema of the collection.

Comment: I have already added.
mongoose.model('Image', Image);

Comment: Can you include the `Image` schema definition code in your post?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by sorting in this way:

```
image.find({reviewed:true },{limit:10},{sort:{"submittedDate":-1}}, function (err, images){
}
```